# Integrating cute-slider with HTML5Boilerplate

Tags: html, css, html5boilerplate

When optimizing a page containing cute-slider using HTML5Boilerplate the slideshow drops by approximately 15px and the list-style disc’s return. This can be seen at http://www.quailparkoflynnwood.com/dev/index.htm (uncompressed) and http://www.quailparkoflynnwood.com/dev/publish/index.htm (compressed). Any insight into pinpointing the cause of this would be greatly appreciated. My fallback is to simply not compress pages containing the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I see no slider, the image with a disc it's actually an image within a list item, so you got an unordered list inside the div#slideshow; maybe normalize.css didn't override the style rules for unordered lists.

Add the following code to a style tag or a css file to remove that styling

```
#slideshow ul {
list-style-type: none !important; /*remove disc !important to override other rules */
padding: 0;
```

}

Your site has an Page Speed score of 51/100 :(
you got plenty of 404's (bad requests to non exixtent resources) and big images (also not optimized). 84c8a31.css it's huge and minified, and seem to have repetitive style rules.

Personally i wouldn´t use js/css minifcation because it makes very complicated further maintenance in exchange for saving som kb's and a couple requests, it's note very cost/effective in my opinion (for regular-sized websites).

If you want to optimize your site start optimizing and resizing your images, find and remove all the bad requests you're making, try to load just one or two css files with style rules you actually use, put scripts at the end.

When you're ready to go:  gzip files and add cache headers with an .htaccess file

Good Luck developer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that cute-slider styles were not being included in the final compressed output. This was remedied by using main.css to hold import statements for all the css files. In earlier versions of HTML5boilerplate, this was the correct coding. My reading of HTML5bp v4.1.0 seems to imply this is no longer the expected setup, but the latest version of the Build (v1.0) still expects the import statements.